# Dataadapter2 is not declared

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using the below code to create a datagridview.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

> ' ***Other code here to import a file***

Then the below code to build a datatable

```
Dim sql2 As String = "SELECT i.[ID],i.[Site],i.[CLI],i.[CustomerName],i.[FromDate],i.[ToDate],i.[Quantity],i.[UnitCost],i.[TotalCost],i.[Description],i.[filenameonly],i.billingmonth as [CurrentBillingMonth], i.[bill] From [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i LEFT JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[" + TextBox1.Text + "] s on i.[SITE]=s.[SITE] AND i.[CLI]=s.[CLI] AND i.[Quantity]=s.[Quantity] AND i.[UnitCost]=s.[UnitCost] AND i.[TotalCost]=s.[TotalCost] AND i.[Description]=s.[Description] WHERE s.[CLI] is NULL"
Dim comm2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql2, conn)
Dim dataadapter2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm2)


'Fill Table
dataadapter2.Fill(ds, "Missing")
DataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = False
DataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables("Missing")
```

I want to create a button on the form to save back to the database, for example

```
Private Sub Button4_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    'Save updated Customer DataGridView
    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter2)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter2.Update(ds.Tables("Missing"))

End Sub
```

The trouble is for Button4 I get an error saying that dataadapter2 is not declared

How can I construct the code so that it is accessible for Button4>

I tried adding the DIM's to the top level class, but that caused other issues, by way of a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when opening the form.

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: See [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: It needs to be class level to be used in more than one sub, the problem is likely the `comm2` object has not been initialized yet

Comment: conn has been initialized at the class level, the trouble is when I define the SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommand at the class level. I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

Comment: You need a better approach, like a `DAL` layer. Your form would call a method on the `DAL` to retrieve info. The `DAL` would initialize and query data and ship it back. `DAL` = `Data Access Layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare dataadapter2  Publicly so u can access it from ur other functions

Comment: If I define all of my dataadapters in the top level PUBLIC class, so that it is available everywhere. It errors ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I open the form

Comment: your object reference error might be comes from other part not from dataadapter2 just check

Comment: My problem is I need the dataadapters to be globally available. It does work if I make it Private, but then I can't create a save button that users the dataadapter because it is not available

Comment: Create a Module and Declared your dataadapter variable in it....initialized it in your working form.so you probably use it everywhere